# Can I prevent Ublock from giving the opportunity to disable strict blocking?

Tags: ublock

I'm setting up some rules on the computer for the laptop of my friend's son.
I'm using Ublock to block some websites, and there is a well-known forum in France where people are really mad and sick, and my friend insisted for me to block specifically that part of the website (because there are a lot of forums on the website), but not the rest.
So I used the rule www.example.com/that-forum.htm^$document so it blocks the main page (topic list) of that forum.

But, as I test the filter, it works but ublock still gives the opportunity to unblock temporarily or permanently the page. My friend really want to make that part of the website unaccessible without tooling with the settings of Ublock.
So the question: can I just block a page from a website without the opportunity to get access temporarily/permanently?